# Record Updating in Database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm updating a Patient record in a database, but when I update it, it overwrites the original record.

I want to keep both entries, but the Primary Key won't allow me to have multiple records for the same patient.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do an `Insert` instead of an `Update`?  You need to give a lot more information than this if you expect anyone to help you.

Comment: Yes, you can, but you will need to change the primary key definition for the table.

Comment: As above comment it's always best to show some code to get better help

Comment: please show expected result and actual result

Answer (score 0):

You can use composite primary key for this, have a look on below example:

```
create table table1 
(
    ID int not null, 
    Number int not null, 
    Name nvarchar(30), 
    Note nvarchar(30), 
    DateCreated datetime
)
go

alter table table1 add constraint PK_table1 primary key (ID, Number)
go

insert into table1 
values(1, 1, 'John', null, getdate()),
    (2, 1, 'Maria', null, getdate()),
    (3, 1, 'Simon', null, getdate()),
    (4, 1, 'Alex', null, getdate())
go

select * from table1

-- insert
insert into table1 
values (1, 2, 'John', 'changed address', getdate())
go

select * from table1

-- drop table table1
```

or just use lookup table which references to main's table primary key (better solution most of the time).

Answer (score -2):

If you do an update, the result is overwrite the record. You have to do a insert instead of a update, but if you have a restriction with a primary key, you will get a exception. Try deleting this primary key (or unique key), if posible.